# Cannot access view - json

Tags: jquery, json, grid, telerik, nopcommerce

Iv'e made a grid for my view using telerik and girdaction attribut. When i run the application i can't access the view and i get an error saying:

***This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.***

My Controller looks like this where ActionResult "OrderDetailsReport" should return a list of order objects in a grid to the view:

```
public class GAStatisticsController : Controller
 {

    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult GetOrderDetails(GridCommand command, GAStatisticsListModel model)
    {


        DateTime? startDateValue = (model.StartDate == null) ? null
                        : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.StartDate.Date, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone);

        DateTime? endDateValue = (model.EndDate == null) ? null
                        : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.EndDate.Date, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone).AddDays(1);

        OrderStatus? orderStatus = model.OrderStatusId > 0 ? (OrderStatus?)(model.OrderStatusId) : null;
        PaymentStatus? paymentStatus = model.PaymentStatusId > 0 ? (PaymentStatus?)(model.PaymentStatusId) : null;
        ShippingStatus? shippingStatus = model.ShippingStatusId > 0 ? (ShippingStatus?)(model.ShippingStatusId) : null;


        var orders = _orderService.SearchOrderStatistics(startDateValue, endDateValue, orderStatus,
            paymentStatus, shippingStatus, model.CustomerEmail, model.OrderGuid);


        var resultOrders = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel(s.Key, s.Count(), s.Sum(x => x.OrderProductVariants.Count()))).ToList();


        List<GCOrdersModel> TotalOrdersPaid = new List<GCOrdersModel>();
        foreach (var r in resultOrders)
        {

            TotalOrdersPaid.Add(r);
        }



        var Orders = TotalOrdersPaid;


        var OrderModel = new GridModel<GCOrdersModel>
        {
            Data = Orders,
            Total = Orders.Count
        };

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = OrderModel
        };

    }

 }
```

The view looks like this ( The grid is suposed to load data depending on what StartDate and EndDate the user has choosen with the @Html.EditorFor dateTimePickers. When clicking submit the data shhould be loaded however im not even able to access the view at all atm):

```
@model GAStatisticsListModel

    @using Nop.Admin.Models.GAStatistics;
    @using Nop.Admin.Controllers;
    @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Html;
    @using System.Web.Mvc;
    @using System.Linq;

    @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "GetOrderDetails";
        Layout = "~/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm(GCOrdersModel))
    {

    <h2>GetOrderDetails</h2>

    <p>Hesan!</p>

    <table class="adminContent">
             <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StartDate):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.EndDate):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.GAStatisticsId ):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.DropDownList("GAStatisticsId", Model.AvailableGAStatistics)
                    <input type="button" id="GAStatisticsReport-Submit" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Search")" />
            </tr>
    </table>


    <table class="adminContent">
            <tr>
                <td>
              @(Html.Telerik().Grid<GCOrdersModel>()
                        .Name("orderDetails-grid")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Date);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.TotalOrders);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.TotalProducts)

                        }
                        )
                        .Groupable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(20).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetOrderDetails", "GAStatistics"))
                        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                        )
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <script>
        var first = true;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if ($("select[name='GAStatisticsId'] option:selected").text() == "OrderStatistics")
                onDataBinding()

            $("#GAStatisticsReport-Submit").click(function () {
                //search
                var grid = $('#orderDetails-grid').data('tGrid');
                grid.currentPage = 1; //new search. Set page size to 1
                grid.ajaxRequest();
                return false;
            })


            function onDataBinding(e) {
                if (first) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    first = false;
                }
                else {


                    var searchModel = {
                        StartDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.StartDate)').val(),
                        EndDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.EndDate)').val()
                    };
                    e.data = searchModel;

                }
            }

        });

    </script>
    }
```

Anny idea why i cant acces the view? Do i have to put "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently returning a `JsonResult`. To return a `ViewResult`, use something like

```
return View(model);
```

or

```
return View("ViewName", model);
```